# Is there a way to scrape a page with XHR autoload?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

there is this site with telegram chats of neighbours in Moscow.
*https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/novostroyki*
i need to scrape it and get links to every card on this site.

the trick is: cards are being appended by XHR when user is reaching the bottom of the page and *requests* can't get them all. is there a way to load them all at once? i've done my research and found out that i can use *Selenium* for it somehow. where do i start?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BlueRobin no problem. import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.post("https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/service.php",data={'type':'get_novostroyli_objects'})
r = requests.get('https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/novostroyki')
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('h3')
print(links)

Comment: @BlueRobin i used this code, maybe not the sharpest tool in the shed, but works fine before i understood that this site is using XHR to add cards as you spin to the bottom. and then it becomes hard. on this site request is called service.php but when i try to request it i only get something like "undefined index or something"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I quess you need to something like this (any question you can ask freely, i dont know about xhr but this code can scrape the card urls):**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = "https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/novostroyki"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="<DRIVERPATH>/chromedriver")
driver.get(main_url)
page_source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
list_items = soup.find_all("div", attrs = {"class":"col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 m-b-30"})

url_list = []

for x in range(len(list_items)):

    try:

        xpath = '//*[@id="showmore-list"]/div[' + str(x+1) + ']/div/a'

        li_item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).get_attribute("href")
        url = { 'url' : li_item }

        url_list.append(url)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue



print(url_list)
```

Comment: It only returns first one

Comment: Ok, i edit the answer, now you can scrap the showing cards (not with selenium, by using beautifulsoup) however if you want to scroll the page and get all of the cards also you should add scroll code before find_all elements.

Answer (score 0):

> i've done my research and found out that i can use Selenium for it somehow

No need to use Selenium - it's an overkill for this kind of task. Instead you can use simple HTTP requests to emulate the "bottom of the page" load behaviour.

Just iterate over pages in XHR requests and print found apartment URLs:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {
    'referer': 'https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/novostroyki',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}


def find_apartment_urls() -> None:
    page_number = 1
    while True:
        with requests.Session() as sess:
            # get a root page to get and save cookies necessary for other requests
            _ = sess.get('https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/novostroyki')
            
            # prepare an XHR request
            resp = sess.post(
                'https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/service.php',
                data=dict(
                    type='get_novostroyli_objects',  # a typo in API here
                    page=page_number,
                    city=3,
                ),
                headers=HEADERS,
            )

            # extract hrefs from XHR response; can also be done with regexp
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
            apartment_urls = {x.get('href') for x in soup.findAll('a')}

            # print results; check if the end is reached
            if apartment_urls:
                print(f'Apartments found on page #{page_number}: '
                      f'{", ".join(apartment_urls)}')
                page_number += 1
            else:
                print('Search is finished.')  # no data == last page is reached
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_apartment_urls()
```

Output:

```bash
Apartments found on page 1: https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/lyublinskiy_park_2253, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/triniti, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/myakinino_park, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/kronshtadtskiy_9_2671, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/life_varshavskaya, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/d1, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/green_park_2428, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/wellton_towers, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/baltiyskiy, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/jazz, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/now_kvartal_na_naberezhnoy, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/dmitrovskiy_park_2889
Apartments found on page 2: https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/sheremetevskiy, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/mihaylovskiy_park, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/stolichnye_polyany, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/volzhskiy_park_2554, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/aquatoria, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/bolshaya_ochakovskaya_2, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/river_park_3047, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/pervyy_moskovskiy, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/savelovskiy_siti_2064, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/seliger_siti, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/salarevo_park, https://moscow.chatnovosela.ru/object/lyubov_i_golubi
...
```